# Maven failing to download artifact from central repository

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I have two private Artifactory repositories setup. One repository handles releases and the other handles snapshots. Here is how I have defined this in my `settings.xml` file.

```xml
<settings>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <username>private-repo-username</username>
            <password>private-repo-password</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>private-repo-username</username>
            <password>private-repo-password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>a0d2olsx0t222-artifactory-primary-0-releases</name>
                    <url>https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>a0d2olsx0t222-artifactory-primary-0-snapshots</name>
                    <url>https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Multiple of my internal dependencies in my multi-module maven project are getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project platform-utils: Could not resolve dependencies for project
design.colspalinva:platform-utils:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:jar:2.12.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.5: Could not find artifact 
com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:jar:2.12.0 in central (https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-
release) -> [Help 1]
```

From the look of it, it doesn't appear that Maven is trying to reach out to the official Maven Central repo for those dependencies, rather failing on my private repository. I was under the impression that if the private repository does not contain the specific artifact, it will attempt to reach out to Maven Central.

It has no problem downloading my Spring dependencies from Maven Central.

Comment: You are not downloading from central you are downloading from an artifactory instance in between which fails `Could not find artifact com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:jar:2.12.0 in central (https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]`...

Comment: @khmarbaise I renamed `<id>central</id>` to something else. Wasn't aware that `central` was a reserved ID for overriding Maven central. Go figure.

Comment: If you like to make sure that anything which is required being downloading through the artifactory you have to define a mirror entry in your settings.xml otherwise this will not work...And it has nothing to do with the id... the error message shows the issue.

Comment: @khmarbaise Would you mind posting an answer with an example of a mirror repo, based on the settings.xml provided?

Comment: @user0000001 from the log it looks like Maven is trying to resolve from Artifactory. The issue might be with the configuration of the repository in Artifactory. Did you try resolving the artifact directly from Artifactory? you can try running a trace to see where is the resolution issue - for example https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release/com/maxmind/geoip2/geoip2-2.12.0.jar?trace

Answer (score 1):

If you like to redirect all access of central from Maven to your own repository manager you have to configure the `settings.xml` as follows:

```
<! language:language-xml ->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
   xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <mirrors>
      <mirror>
         <id>nexus</id>
         <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
         <url>http://IP:PORT/repository/repo</url>
      </mirror>
   </mirrors>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>nexus</id>
         <repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>central</id>
               <url>http://central</url>
               <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                  <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
               </releases>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                  <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
               </snapshots>
            </repository>
         </repositories>
         <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
               <id>central</id>
               <url>http://central</url>
               <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                  <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
               </releases>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                  <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
               </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
         </pluginRepositories>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <activeProfiles>
      <!--make the profile active all the time -->
      <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I will give this a try. I'm wondering though, should I even specify the maven central repositories under `<repositories>`? Wouldn't the mirror be enough?

Comment: Usually yes but I strongly recommend that to be abled to control the configuration for updatePolicy and checksumPolicy...

Answer (score 1):

The Maven settings.xml configuration you shared seems to be OK. You are [overriding](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-ManuallyOverridingtheBuilt-inRepositories) the built-in central and snapshot repositories of Maven, which is the correct way to make sure that Maven send requests by default to Artifactory.
Adding a [Mirror Any](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-AdditionalMirrorAnySetup) setting, as suggested in the other answer, means that in addition to overriding built-in Maven repositories, you can use the Mirror Any setting to redirect all requests to a Maven repository through Artifactory, including those defined inside POMs of plug-ins and third party dependencies.

According to the log you shared Maven does attempt to resolve the artifacts via Artifactory - https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release
The issue seems to be related to resolution of a specific artifact(s)in Artifactory.
I'm assuming that libs-release is a [virtual](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories) Maven repository and that it contains at least one [remote](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Remote+Repositories) Maven repository pointing at Jcenter or Maven Central (if not please start by looking at [Maven Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository)).
To debug the issue:

(1) Try resolving the artifact directly from Artifactory using cURL or a web browser, for example:

```
curl -Uuser:pass https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release/com/maxmind/geoip2/geoip2/2.12.0/geoip2-2.12.0.jar
```

(2) If you manage to resolve the artifact, it mean that Artifactory is properly configured and Maven should be able to resolve. If not, try looking for the reason performing a trace, for example:

```
curl -Uuser:pass https://my-private-repo.jfrog.io/artifactory/libs-release/com/maxmind/geoip2/geoip2/2.12.0/geoip2-2.12.0.jar?trace
```